React router V6 - how to set React key on route element based from parameter
In react-router V6, can you still use a parameter as React key?
In react-router V5, this could be achieved by writing:
<Switch>
  <Route path="products/:productId" render={({match}) => <ProductDetail key={match.params.productId}/>} />
</Switch>

Now, after the switch to react-router V6, how do you pass the key?
<Routes>
  <Route path="products/:productId" element={<ProductDetail key={?}/>}/>
</Routes>

Or is that no longer possible and should you add a wrapper container, which receives the productId param from useParams() and passes it on?
MyWrapper = () => {
  const { productId} = useParams();
  return <ProductDetail key={productId}/>;
}


if you are using function component you can directly use useParams hook inside, don't need any wrapper

@YuvarajM yes I know I can use useParams directly inside ProductDetail, but that was not the question. I want to use it in the <Route >

You have already answered your question

You already seem to have answered your own question in the post with the MyWrapper component. That said, can you still use a React key, yes, sure, but you really should use the useParams hook in the ProductDetail component combined with a useEffect hook if you need to run different logic based on the value.

You can create a HOD (Higher order component) which takes component as a prop, that would eliminate creating wrappers each time.
Wrapper
function MyWrapper = ({component:Component}) => {
    const { productId} = useParams();
    return <Component key={productId}/>;
}

Route
<Routes>
  <Route path="products/:productId" element={<MyWrapper component={ProductDetail}/>} />
  <Route path="products2/:productId2" element={<MyWrapper component={ProductDetail2}/>} />
</Routes>



const ProductDetailWrapper = () => {
 const { productId } = useParams();
 return <ProductDetail key={productId} />;
};

const App = () => {
 return (
   <Routes>
     <Route path="products/:productId" element={<ProductDetailWrapper />} />
   </Routes>
 );
};


Yes, this is how we did it- but it seems to be a bit wrong we have to each time create ourselves these wrappers. I was wondering if there isn't a better/cleaner solution.
